# Skip null columns while sink in mapping dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

**Needed Solve**: Need to skip if column value coming as NULL from data source so that it won't overwrite the existing values.

**Scenario** : I'm processing CDC of a master table and referenced table. To get CDC changes from both tables based on master table doing a left join between master & reference CDC data.
In scenario where there is change happened in master table only, then in left join the reference data will come as nulls for all columns. In mapping dataflow the reference column values in target getting overridden as NULLS.

any suggestions how to skip the columns with null values in dataflow ?

[image]

The reason for left join is that, there is very high chance changes will happen only in table1 but not table 2.

Comment: what's the source and sink table? We are not very clear. Can you show us your Mapping data flow overview page?

Comment: Hi Leon, I have updated the question with scenario image, hope that helps to understand

Comment: Hi VT0906, you could  add DerivedColumn after the left join. then using expression like `case(isNull(source1@name),source2@name)` to replace the null value. The expression means that if the `source1@name` is null, then replace it with `source2@name`.